# sympy symbolic fft of 1/cosh(x)

Tags: python, numpy, plot, fft, sympy

I'm trying to compute the symbolic fft of $1/cosh(x)$ via

```
# %%
import sympy as sp 
import numpy as np 
import sympy.abc as spa

g = sp.fourier_transform(1/sp.cosh(spa.x), spa.x, spa.k)
print(g)
sp.plot(g)
```

but keep getting the error

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sympy\plotting\experimental_lambdify.py
> in __call__(self, args)
>     175             #The result can be sympy.Float. Hence wrap it with complex type.
> --> 176             result = complex(self.lambda_func(args))
>     177             if abs(result.imag) > 1e-7 * abs(result):
> 
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sympy\plotting\experimental_lambdify.py
> in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
>     271     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
> --> 272         return self.lambda_func(*args, **kwargs)
>     273 
> 
> <string> in <lambda>(x0)
```

any ideas what this means?

Comment: When I run the code, I get "can't convert expression to float".   To actually plot the graph, sympy has to actually symbolically  evaluate the fourier transform of 1/cosh, and I suspect it's having trouble doing so.

Comment: @jimbob97, did you notice that `fourier_transform` was not able to do the Fourier transform of `1/cosh(spa.x)`?  It returns the unevaluated result `FourierTransform(1/cosh(x), x, k)`.

Comment: Yes I did, not sure why

Answer (score 0):

In a `isympy` session:

```
In [40]: g = fourier_transform(1/cosh(x),x,k)

In [41]: g
Out[41]: 
                ⎛   1         ⎞
FourierTransform⎜───────, x, k⎟
                ⎝cosh(x)      ⎠

In [42]: plot(g)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py:188: UserWarning: The evaluation of the expression is problematic. We are trying a failback method that may still work. Please report this as a bug.
  return self.__call__(args)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py:176, in lambdify.__call__(self, args)
    174 try:
    175     #The result can be sympy.Float. Hence wrap it with complex type.
--> 176     result = complex(self.lambda_func(args))
    177     if abs(result.imag) > 1e-7 * abs(result):

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py:272, in Lambdifier.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    271 def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 272     return self.lambda_func(*args, **kwargs)

File <string>:1, in <lambda>(x0)
....
File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.py:345, in Expr.__float__(self)
    343 if result.is_number and result.as_real_imag()[1]:
    344     raise TypeError("Cannot convert complex to float")
--> 345 raise TypeError("Cannot convert expression to float")

TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float
```

I was going to complain about an incomplete traceback, but it is very long.  Still you left off the final block, the one with the error

```
 Cannot convert expression to float
```

You `print(g)`; why didn't you show that?  Please show as much information as you can.  It helps those of us who can't replicated your code (at the moment).

---

I haven't worked with this before, but even if I use `subs` to replace the variables with numbers, it still doesn't yield a numeric value.  So there's nothing to plot.

```
In [52]: g.subs({x:2,k:3}).evalf()
Out[52]: 
                ⎛   1         ⎞
FourierTransform⎜───────, 2, 3⎟
                ⎝cosh(2)      ⎠
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative reply. Hmm, what do I need to do in order to get the plot? I Can do it in Mathematica no probs but not in Python?